# ctrl+e followed by another character inserts ♑ character

Tags: keyboard, emoji

When using Chrome, and only in some text boxes, the ♑ character (Capricorn, U+2651) gets inserted after using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> shortcut to move the cursor to the end of the line.

How can I disable this behavior?

- Chrome: Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Mac: Version 12.0.1 (21A559)
- Keyboard: US (builtin laptop keybooard)
- Language: English
- Region: United States

Comment: which version of Chrome? Which version of MacOS? Language & Keyboard layout?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The standard key shortcut to move the cursor to the end of the current line is Command+Right Arrow (see https://support.apple.com/HT201236). My experience is that Control+E works in some editors and in Terminal (with `bash`, at least), but it is not supported universally.

Comment: It's supported where an application uses standard text tcontrols.  You'll note that the OP's problem is not that it doesn't work, it does work but inserts an extra character.

Comment: Two things... one, why are you running such an old macOS with known security problems, and two, are you running any keyboard manipulators, such as Karabiner, Text Expander, Typinator, etc.

Comment: I have disabled the Chrome Extension SurfingKeys for evernote.com to resolve this issue: `settings.blacklistPattern = /evernote.com.*/i`.

Comment: SurfingKeys was the problem. Thanks so much @Hotschke !

Answer (score 0):

### Disable Chrome Extension Surfing Keys for evernote.com

`settings.blacklistPattern = /evernote.com.*/i`

### General Advice

to figure out unexpected behaviour when pressing key chords, disable all third party programs related to keyboard mappings and re-enable only each one on its own.

#### Possible Third Party Programs

- Browser Extensions

  - [SurfingKeys](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys)
  - [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium)
  - ...
- [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)
- [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd)
- [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/)
- [Phoenix](https://kasper.github.io/phoenix/)
- [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/)
- [AltTab](https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos)
- [Dash Snippets](https://kapeli.com/dash_guide#introductionToSnippets)
- ...

#### Customised System Settings

- Shortcuts
- Text Expansion
- Behaviour of Modifier Keys
- Keyboard Layout
- Accessibility Settings

should also be checked.